# Post edited by others but OP not notified

Tags: bug, notifications

When posts are edited by others, the OP gets a notification in the Inbox.

This post was edited about an hour ago (20:50:02Z): [revision 3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/159088/revisions) but the latest notification in my Inbox is from 12 hours ago.

Has anything changed or is this a bug? Or perhaps a lag in the scripts due to the overwhelming Hat activity?

Comment: @AndriyM nice! (no notification for this edit either!)

Comment: Same for me here. http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/159083/revisions